# Parsing a large json file using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a really big json to read and store into database. I am using mix mode of stream and object using gson. If file format is correct it works like a charm. but if format is not correct within an object then whole file is skipped with an exception (reader.hasNext() throws exception).

Is there a way to skip a particular bad record and continue to read with rest of file?

Sample json file structure -
 [{
  "A":1,
  "B":2,
  "C":3
  }]
and let say comma or colon is missing in this object.

Another example is if there are multiple objects and comma is missing between }(no comma){ 2 objects.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the producer to provide valid JSON. It is the responsibility of the consumer to only allow valid JSON. Attempting to process malformed data is unsafe.

Comment: @Compass I understand that but there are chance that some of the data is not in correct json format and this is causing to stop execution of all of the records.

Comment: If it's not in the correct format, you should not be processing it. By attempting to process corrupt or incorrect data, you are taking responsibility for any mistakes that occur based on your potentially incorrect interpretation of that data, rather than going to the source and asking them to fix their data.

Comment: Well you are correct but there is only option for me which is to skip those bad data and move on to next record.

Comment: You should never say "really big" without giving the magnitude. For a physicist a "very long time" may mean a femtosecond.

Answer (score 0):

> let say comma or colon is missing in this object

Unfortunately if you're missing a comma or a colon, then it's impossible to parse the JSON data.

**But:** 
it's actually a good thing the parser doesn't accept this data because it protects you from *accidentally* reading garbage. Since you are putting this data into a database, it's protecting you from potentially filling your database with garbage.

I believe the best solution is to fix the producer of this JSON data and implement the necessary safe guards to prevent bad JSON data in the future.